# Python3 OpenCV3 Abort trap:6

Tags: python, django, opencv

After the installation of Python3 and OpenCV3, I tried to detect faces in a image with the following code:

```
...
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
faces = detector.detectMultiScale(image, 2.0, 5)
```

After calling detectMultiScale, Django/Python freezes and I get a SIGABRT error.
I checked that the detector and the image are loaded correctly.